# What is model.predict(x.head) really predicting when using DecisionTreeRegressor from sklearn.tree?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I used `predict` from scikit-learn DecisionTreeRegressor to try to model some March Madness stats, but I don't really know what my result means.

What does the `predict` function predict? Is it an estimate of what comes next in the columns or is solving it like you would a matrix?

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

model = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)
model.fit(x, y)

#file_path_test = '/content/sample_data/MM_Prediction_21 - Sheet5.csv'
data_test = pd.read_csv(file_path)
x1 = data_test[features]

print(model.predict(x1.head()))
```

Comment: *what does the predict function predict*, predicts labels or values of the given data.

Comment: A ML Model 'learns' from the example X_train and y_train you gave him during training, and try to build a model from it. Then it applies the model to the new X_new you give and ask him to predict the y_new value.

Comment: Okay, so what happened when you tried to read the documentation? Do you have any background understanding of machine learning?

Answer (score 0):

`model.predict` predicts values based on the feature using the model fitted above. In this specific case its a [`DecisionTreeClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree) which builds a [`Decision Tree`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree). During prediction phase, tree built is used to predict on which leaf node each of the feature vector falls in and the class label in that leaf node is outputted.